# C# Select Transact-SQL (Table Column Property)

Tags: c#, sql, datarow

I wanna select Table Column property using c#. I wrote this code. My query is working on the sqlserver. But i dont get max length in c#.

**My Query Is Here**

```
//TableName:Contents, ColumnName : Title
select Col_Length('Contents','Title') as columnLengthh
```

**Result Is Here:**

[image]

**My C# Code Here :**

```
string columnLength = "select Col_Length('Contents','Title') as columnLengthh";
                    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(columnLength, connection);
                    dataSet = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(dataSet);
                    DataTable dataTable2 = dataSet.Tables[0];
                    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable2.Rows)
                    {
                        var x  = row["columnLengthh"].ToString();
                    }
```

Result (x = -1)

**How i get length in c#.**

**Please help!**

Comment: Your statement returns a single value, you should not be using an adapter/dataset instead simply call command.ExecuteScalar()

Comment: Check your connection. Besides unnecessary overhead of creating Dataset and DataTable i see nothing wrong in your code. -1 is a legitimite `COL_LENGTH()` value : For columns of type varchar declared with the max specifier (`varchar(max)`),`COL_LENGTH` returns the value –1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your query is correct

Change the connectionString to match what you have - for example:

```
   string connectionString = @"server=localhost\mysqlserver;database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;";
```

and use the following code:

```
        string queryString = "select Col_Length('Contents','Title') as columnLengthh";
        string connectionString = @"your con string";
        SqlConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
                Console.WriteLine("columnLengthh = {0}", result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: No probs. Good luck. Feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlReader` etc classes to communicate to SQL Server.

```
string queryString = "select Col_Length('Contents','Title') as columnLengthh";
string connectionString = "Your connection string";
SqlConnection connection = null;
try
{
    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection)) ;
    {
        connection.Open();
        var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
        Console.WriteLine("columnLengthh = {0}", result);
    }
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: This should also dispose of the command object. Also the reader isn't used.

Comment: @stuartd Thanks. I corrected it. for reader it is not using reader object.

Comment: You've still left in the call to ExecuteReader, which means the call to ExecuteScalar will not work!

Comment: Jenish Rabadiya thanks for the reply. I tried this code. But result return -1.

Comment: @stuartd he he so stupid. Updated the code now... :)

Comment: Use a `try` `catch` `finally` to open the connection so that `finally` will always be `connection.Close();`

Comment: @AndroidDvlpr whats your connection string? This should work. I tried it on my own db and it worked fine.